# out-ping nodejs package installation error

Tags: node.js

I have code that I need to run on my laptop but whenever I try to install (out-ping package) it shows this error, I tried to install (fsevents) to solve the error it didn't work too plz help me thank you.

PS C:\Users\admin\nodeex> npm i net-ping --save
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

> raw-socket@1.7.0 install C:\Users\admin\nodeex\node_modules\raw-socket
> node-gyp rebuild

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQOZW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GF7r.png)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please ensure you include the [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can ensure we assist you as best as we can.

Comment: it's my first time to post coding errors. I will try to make it clear as much as possible  the problem is I can't install the net-ping package  the outcome error is too long i attached  image number 2 with 2links error code if you don't mind can you check it